# Qué significa «pasi»

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, significado-en-contexto

¿Que significa "pasi" en "andar pasi trotero", en la canción «La Potra Zaina» de Juan Vicente Torrealba?

> Les contaré señores
> La historia muy bonita
> De linda potranquita
> Con ojos soñadores
> Colita de caballo
> **Andar pasi trotero**

Answer (score 2):

En esta canción, la palabra *pasitrotero* se convierte en "pasi trotero", pienso que por cuestiones musicales. Y según el Diccionario de la Lengua:

**pasitrotero**. Aire más rápido que el paso y más cómodo que el trote, que adoptan, con frecuencia, los asnos, y, raras veces, las demás caballerías.

Comment: Parece que _pasitrotero_ viniera de _paso trotero_, con esa [o] reemplazada por [i] por asimilación o algún otro fenómeno de evolución fonética.

Answer (score 1):

En el diccionario "Llanero" de Hugo Mantillas Trejos, aparece la voz "Pasitrotero" definida de la siguiente manera;

- **Pasitrotero**. adj. Se dice del caballo criollo de andar elegante.

Por tanto entiendo que "pasi trotero", se refiere en este caso, al paso elegante que tiene la "linda potranquita".